# Confusing CSS rules precedence

Tags: css, operator-precedence

I have this (simplified) markup:

```
<ul id="topnav">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li id="last-nav">last</li>
</ul>
```

and these CSS rules:

```
#topnav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}

#last-nav {
    float: right;
}
```

To my surprise, the second rule is overruled by the first one. If I change the selector to `li#last-nav`, it works. Why is that?

(Disclaimer: I only tested this in Firefox)

Comment: wow, thanks guys for all these great answers! Sometimes I hate the fact that I can accept only one answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cascade works like this:

1. The more important rule applies.
2. If equally important, the more specific rule applies.
3. If equally specific, the latter rule applies.

Here, `#topnav li` has a [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity) of 101, and `#last-nav` has a specificity of 100, so the first one wins. A selector of `li#last-nav` or `#topnav #last-nav` would be more specific.

Comment: li#last-nav would be equally specific, but would take precedence since it comes later in the top-down order, but other than that, this is mostly correct. I don't like showing CSS specificity values as a single number, because it's really not. It's a combination of 4 (when you count inline styles), so it's more like 1|0|1 and 1|0|0.

Comment: @Russell good point; I think the last time I read about specificity (was it that long ago?) it was using the older notation with only three values and no separators.

Answer (score 6):

Read up on CSS Specificity:

http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html
http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/link-specificity.html

Essentially, the first selector is more specific than the second, so it takes precedence. It's not about top-down order in CSS. Top-down order only applies if both selectors are equally specific.

Answer (score 6):

**Selector Rules: Calculating Specificity**

Style sheets can also override conflicting style sheets based on their level of specificity, where a more specific style will always win out over a less specific one. It is simply a counting game to calculate the specificity of a selector.

- Count the number of ID attributes in the selector.
- Count the number of CLASS attributes in the selector.
- Count the number of HTML tag names in the selector.

Finally, write the three numbers in exact order with no spaces or commas to obtain a three digit number. (Note, you may need to convert the numbers to a larger base to end up with three digits.) The final list of numbers corresponding to selectors will easily determine specificity with the higher numbers winning out over lower numbers. Following is a list of selectors sorted by specificity:

```
#id1         {xxx} /* a=1 b=0 c=0 --> specificity = 100 */
UL UL LI.red {xxx} /* a=0 b=1 c=3 --> specificity = 013 */
LI.red       {xxx} /* a=0 b=1 c=1 --> specificity = 011 */
LI           {xxx} /* a=0 b=0 c=1 --> specificity = 001 */
```

In your example `#topnav li` is 101 and `#last-nav` is only 100, so 101 wins.

Cited from http://htmlhelp.com/reference/css/structure.html

Comment: I think you mean that `#topnav is 100`, not that `#topnav li is 100`. (The last but one sentence.)

Comment: I think he meant `#last-nav` - I edited the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

You can explain this with specificity.

Think of it like this:

```
Elements etc: 0, 0, 0, 1
Classes: 0, 0, 1, 0
IDs: 0, 1, 0, 0
Inline: 1, 0, 0, 0

#topnav li = 0, 1, 0, 1
#last-nav = 0, 1, 0, 0
```

So #topnav li is more specific and thus gains precedence.

Of course cascading and inhertence and even the use of !important can take other effects on the CSS but in this case, #topnav li is just more specific

Answer (score 1):

The last rule has a lower specificity.  Try changing to:

```
li#last-nav {  }
```

FYI: You can use this tool calc specificity: [Specificity Calculator](http://www.suzyit.com/tools/specificity.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#topnav #last-nav {
    float: right;
}
```

or

```
#last-nav {
    float: right !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, though I suspect, that the first rule is taking precedence because it is being applied to a specific element (li, in this case). The second rule could theoretically apply to any element with an ID of last-nav.

Specificity rules may be coming into play: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Modern browsers would probably let you get away with:

```
#topnav li:last-child {
```

float: right;
}

...and achieve the same outcome to the one you want.

HTH,

G

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with your first style have more specificity than your second. Check out [this site](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) for more details. To get your second style working properly, try using:

```
#topnav #last-nav
```